# Finding and printing the average of a square of values in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

ive been having trouble with a really easy problem, but for some reason i just can't seem to crack the problem, but i feel like im close.  I'd like some input on how far/close i am and what directions i could move in.

Basically, I take in an image as a pnm file and take in the pixel values into a 2d array.  I then have to take in a square of 4 pixels, find the average, and then print it out to a new file, effectively making the image smaller.
e.g. a square containing the 4 pixels:

0  10

12 14
becomes just one value: 9

The main concern are in the loops where i calculate the averages.  I increment by 2 because i only ever want to be looking at a square of values.  I access the indexes of the 4 pixels and initialise temp variables with them, and find the average which i write to the output file.

Unfortunately, i dont seem to be getting the average, and the image being printed is completely wrong.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Master Edit.  Okay with the help everyones given me i seem to have cracked the problem.  The issues weren't arising with the calculation of the average pixel, but with the initialisation of the 2d array.  I confused the two width and height pixel values when declaring so i was taking and using the wrong pixels to calculate.  In the final version the code works fine with any size picture when fixed.  Thanks to everyone for their help, and especially @Geo for pointing out the problem!

Remember: Array[row][column].

Final Code.

```
        /**
         * I take in the values from the pnm file and read in the file type, width, height and
         * max pixels.
         */
        String fileType = readImage.next() ;
        int width = readImage.nextInt() ;
        int height = readImage.nextInt() ;
        int maxPixels = readImage.nextInt() ;

        /**
         * I intialise an array to read in the values of the image and use a loop to set the
         * values.
         */
        int[][] image = new int[height][width] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                image[i][j] = readImage.nextInt() ;

            }
        }

        /**
         * I re-write out the image type, width, height and max pixels.
         */
        readImage.close() ;
        newImage.write(fileType + "\n") ;
        newImage.write(width / 2 + " " + height / 2 + "\n") ;
        newImage.write(maxPixels + "\n") ;

        /**
         * Loop over the array, calculate the average pixel and print
         */
        byte counter = 0 ;
        for (int i = 1; i < height; i += 2)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < width; j += 2)
            {
                int temp0 = image[i - 1][j - 1] ;
                int temp1 = image[i - 1][j] ;
                int temp2 = image[i][j - 1] ;
                int temp3 = image[i][j] ;

                int average = ((temp0 + temp1 + temp2 + temp3) / 4) ;
                newImage.write(average + " ") ;
                counter++ ;
                if (counter == 17)
                {
                    newImage.write("\n") ;
                    counter = 0 ;
                }
            }
        }
        // close the write and image
        newImage.write("\n") ;
        newImage.close() ;
    }

    /**
     * Catch statements to catch File and IO exceptions
     */
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!") ;
    } catch (IOException e2)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: The output image has half as many pixels in each direction as the input image, yet you're still writing out the PGM header with the old width/height values!  And you're sure your input is a "type P2" (i.e. ASCII and not binary) PGM?

Comment: That is a very good point.  I've edited the values to half in my actual code.  The image is the size i assume is right, but the values are still wrong.  Yeah, the filetype is p2.  Original width is 1155 and height is 690.  max pixel size is 255.

Comment: Are there any input pixel values larger than 32767?  If so, try `nextInt()` rather than `nextShort()` when reading the pixels in, to avoid overflowing the signed `short` type (and make your pixel values `int`s).

Comment: The values only go from 0 to 255 in the input file.  The fill loop and the use of short values is actually taken from another example where i had to colour invert an image by subtracting 255 to make white to dark etc.

Comment: Why do you add a new line every 15 iterations?

Comment: you should also consider pnm file with an odd height/width. the edges could become an issue in this case. maybe try with a file that will fit 2*2 squares with no remainder. eg 10*10pnm file will give 25 2*2 squares.

Comment: Once height and width are fixed, it works on my machine.  Can you provide any examples of how the values are "wrong" - input pixel values, actual outputs?

Comment: Thats just for formatting the numbers when you look at it in the text editor, otherwise its just a long block of numbers. I've tried it with and without that code and with different values apart from 15 and it doesnt change anything.

Comment: @pobrelkey Well this is the input file i take in http://www.filedropper.com/computerscience-in 
and this is the output file my program creates
http://www.filedropper.com/newcomputerscience 
At first glance the numbers dont seem to be correct, although that may be to do with the in-eclipse text editor.

The dimension comment is a good point, the file i take in happens to be odd, but how could i make assumptions about a file i take in without knowing the dimensions, and how would this alter my program?  I wouldnt necessarily know whether a picture is even or odd before the program starts

Comment: Hold on.  It happened to work for me because I was using a square image...

Comment: The question does actually say that i should assume the file is 2nx2m, and make a new file nxm.  I think i may have been a bit of an idiot and used an inappropriate test file, although it was the one provided in the question.  Ill find a square image and test it with that now, any good resources for finding a square pnm image to test on? :P

Comment: @th3_great, 2nx2m doesn't mean square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have width and height confused. In the PNM format the pixels come in row-by-row, with `height` as the number of rows and `width` as the length of each row. You are reading the numbers in as if `height` were the length of each row and there were `width` rows. You are also making the same mistake when writing the new pixels out. When I test your code with that corrected it seems to work perfectly.

You are writing a `'\n'` when your `counter` gets to 15 instead of writing the newline when you get to the actual end of the row. That seems like an unnatural place to break the lines, but if you prefer it that way then it shouldn't be a real problem.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, when i open the file in a text editor, the first 4 values i see are p2 which i take to be the file type, 1155 which i assume to be the horizontal length, and 690 which i assume to be vertical length.  
When i first wrote out the program i just tested it by reading in the values and printing them back out to copy the image and see whether my loops were correct and they appeared to be.  Also most of my code is from a lecturer example, my additions are in the block where i 'calculate' the average pixel.  
The counter doesn't have an affect of my output.

Comment: @th3_great, when you do that test it is misleading. You are reading all the numbers into the array and printing them all back in the same order, but it doesn't reveal that the numbers aren't being stored in the correct places inside the array. You have long rows being pushed into short columns and wrapped around multiple columns, so it's no wonder that the result is chaos when you try to do the averaging operation on that array.

Comment: Some people have been reporting success with that code, provided its a square image, which makes sense as im only looking for a square.  Would your suggestion help with looking to convert an uneven image like this one? http://www.filedropper.com/computerscience-in

Comment: @th3_great, naturally they have success with square images because that is the only kind of image where it doesn't matter if you mix up the width and height. If you *don't* mix up width and height, it will work perfectly on any image. I tested it on exactly that image and it works fine.

Comment: Ah i see, so do you mean that i just have the two variables mixed up? I just need to put height where width was and width where height was?
Okay i think ive got it, when i initialised my array i used the wrong varibles.  i switched them around and did the same with the loops it worked.  Thanks for your help, ill think more about the solution and understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine for a square .pnm file. I used the following pnm to test

```
P2
10 10
255
254 254 254 254 252 210 147 109 108 135 143 143 140 140 146 137 135 
134 132 133 131 131 129 130 128 129 127 129 126 127 135 109  55  94 
152 110  92 138 145 163 163 163 160 162 163 168 164 163 165 163 164 
162 167 162 162 161 160 159 162 161 159 161 162 162 161 159 166 163 
168 180  77 127 170 164 159 159 158 156 157 159 157 157 159 158 157 
157 158 158 161 161 161 167 166 166 177 176 180 176 173 173
```

on running your code it produced:

```
P2
5 5
255
198 197 186 131 127 126 102 129 121 140 163 162 163 161 162 
131 164 159 160 166 160 162 166 168 167
```

The first square would be:

```
254 254
143 143
```

average = 198.5 which -> 198 since you are using an `int` to store the value. note that there are 17 entries in each row of the file so the 11/12 entry in the first row of the file is really the first 2 values in the second row. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thats brilliant, thanks for reassuring me.  I got the same results here.  The question was in fact assuming me to read a 2nx2m file so i should have been looking at square images in the first place, but the image they provided is uneven so thats why i was confused.  What type of modifications would i have to do to my code to resize a file like the one that was provided? Link: http://www.filedropper.com/computerscience-in

Comment: @th3_great I dont have time now but i will answer this tomorrow, ignoring the last row/column if it is odd would be a quick fix. some accuracy would be lost but i imagine it would be neglible

Comment: I think i may have fixed it thanks to geo's help.  When i initialised the array i had the width and height mixed up,  when i switched short[width][height] to [height][width] and did the same for the nested loops the resize works, although i could definitely use an explanation as to why it works!